# Data file organized in strings

Tags: programming, string-manipulation

I am working in a data set : [The original question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/exctrating-data-information-from-a-file-txt), They are strings of thousands stars,and each one contains a lot of parameters, and the following item is called identifies, they are the  names (nomenclatures) that a specific star can have in diverse catalogues.

And I need to take the "wordcharaters + numbers "  in this string:

```
"Identifiers (30):
   ALS 3038                        CD-55 5094                      CEL 4238                      
   CPC 19 5018                     CPD-55 5504                     EM* CDS 875                   
   FK5 3065                        GC 18036                        GCRV 64023                    
   GEN# +1.00115842                GSC 08666-01844                 HD 115842                     
   HIC 65129                       HIP 65129                       HR 5027                       
   IRAS 13176-5532                 JP11 2383                       LS 3038                       
   MCW 1248                        NSV 6193                        PPM 341819                    
   ROT 7259                        SAO 240765                      SKY# 24643                    
   TD1 16778                       TYC 8666-1844-1                 UBV 12039                     
   UBV M 19272                     uvby98 100115842                2MASS J13204833-5548026       

Notes (0) :"
```

As follows:

```
   { ALS 3038, CD-55 5094,CEL 4238,CPC 19 5018,...}
```

So I can apply the code to get these names for  thousands stars from my dataset: [the original question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/exctrating-data-information-from-a-file-txt).

And generate a kind of association or DataSet[], as ex. : identifiers (is one of many parameters I have to take):

```
{{star ...., identifiers-> name1, name2,name 3...},{star...,identifiers-> name1, name2, etc...}}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the actual question here? This site is not just for presentation of your current projects.

Comment: I am not presenting my project, I am having some difficulties to get pieces of information. And I am asking for help, I do not understand why you think I am presenting my projects, as everyone  in this forum has question related to his "projects" also.

Comment: You say "I am working", "I need", but not "how can I do...?" or "what is wrong with [given code]?" What exactly do you want us to do for you here?

Comment: ok, I see that you  have issues with the semantics. So yes, "How can I get the names from the identifiers in a string", is it ok for you, now?

Comment: Yes, that's clear now, thank you. Just one other thing: why are you using the [tag:associations] tag when you admit in the other question that you don't know how they work or whether they are even appropriate here? I would suggest tags like [tag:programming] or [tag:string-manipulation] instead. Remember that posts on SE sites are expected to be useful for many people into the future, not just for the temporary benefit of the OP.

Comment: Oleksandr, I do not know much about Dataset[] or Association[]. But, clearly my questions  are connected  to associations/Dataset subjects. Is a new approach that I am learning with Mathematica 10., so sorry if I used the wrong tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19770/discussion-between-locometro-and-oleksandr-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    q = Import["Teste_dataMining.txt"];
    identifiersPositions = StringPosition[q,"Identifiers (" ~~ CharacterRange["0", "9"] .. ~~ "):"];
notes = StringPosition[q,"Notes (" ~~ CharacterRange["0", "9"] .. ~~ ") :"];
identifiers = StringTake[q, Transpose[{identifiersPositions[[All, 2]] + 1, 
    notes[[All, 1]] - 1}]];
StringSplit[identifiers, Whitespace ~~ Whitespace ..]
(*{{"ALS 3038", "CD-55 5094", "CEL 4238", "CPC 19 5018", "CPD-55 5504", 
  "EM* CDS 875", "FK5 3065", "GC 18036", "GCRV 64023", 
  "GEN# +1.00115842", "GSC 08666-01844", "HD 115842", "HIC 65129", 
  "HIP 65129", "HR 5027", "IRAS 13176-5532", "JP11 2383", "LS 3038", 
  "MCW 1248", "NSV 6193", "PPM 341819", "ROT 7259", "SAO 240765", 
  "SKY# 24643", "TD1 16778", "TYC 8666-1844-1", "UBV 12039", 
  "UBV M 19272", "uvby98 100115842", 
  "2MASS J13204833-5548026"}, {"CD-51 7465", "CEL 4244", 
  "CPC 19 5027", "CPD-51 6012", "GC 18081", "GCRV 7935", 
  "GEN# +1.00116084", "GSC 08260-01811", "HD 116084", "HIC 65247", 
  "HIP 65247", "HR 5036", "N30 3060", "PPM 341837", "SAO 240782", 
  "SKY# 24684", "TYC 8260-1811-1", "UBV M 19298", "[B10] 3458", 
  "uvby98 100116084", "2MASS J13221628-5210586", "ALS 14978"}}*)
```